# Spring JUnit: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL

Tags: spring, junit4

I am pretty much new to maven. When I execute `mvn clean install` I get following error in all the test classes during execution. After going through some of the posts on SO and searching through Google, all mentioned JUnit version problem. I cross-checked all my pom files and they have junit version 4.8.2. But, still I keep on getting this error.

```
<testcase time="0.002" classname="com.service.ServiceImpl" name="initializationError0">
<error message="NULL" type="java.lang.NoSuchFieldError">java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.&lt;init&gt;(ParentRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.&lt;init&gt;(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:58)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.&lt;init&gt;(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.buildRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
</error>
</testcase>
```

I ran `mvn dependency:tree` and searched for all junit instances. All of them showed 4.8.2.

Comment: Try running with the -Dmaven.test.skip option. If it goes through, then you might try to run the unit tests in eclipse. Hopefully, that may help to locate the problem.

Comment: What version of Spring?  Could it be an older version that compiles against an earlier version of JUnit?  (they changed the runner in 4.5 or so making this important.)

Comment: I am using Spring 3.1.1.

Comment: I am not sure if it is caused because of EasyMock. I have EasyMock-JUnit version 2.5.1.

Comment: The build works perfectly fine with -Dmaven.test.skip option. However, the jmock-junit4-2.5.1 and junit-4.8.2. I am confused how to solve this. Can I exclude the jmock-junit jar and just use junit-4.8.2? Or I have to downgrade from junit-4.8.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was the issue with jmock-junit4. It was removed by putting following (excluding the junit when importing jmock-junit) --

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```